# What is the name for a partially applied map

Tags: functional-programming

In functional programming most common patterns tend to be given names that help differentiate them.

I am trying to find what the name for a type of function that I would describe as a *partially applied map*.

An example in Python:

```
from functools import partial
seq_len = partial(map, len)
seq_len(['alpha', 'beta', 'charlie'])
```

I understand these could also be described as functions that take sequences as input.

Some functions that I identified as being interesting subjects of such partial application are:

- map
- reduce
- filter

More:

- Python uses the "iterator" name to refer to objects that implement the iterator protocol. But in itertools functions that take sequences and return sequences are also referred to as "iterators"(https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html).
- JavaScript uses identical definition for iterator(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).
- Rust uses the term "consuming adaptors" for methods that *consume* the iterator and "iterator adaptors" for methods that transform the input iterator into a different iterator on output.

Comment: This is related to Transducers, but isn't since transducers can be composed and your partial applicated `map` is just that. The particular partial application should be easy to name though even though I don't think doing it with `map` has a common name.

Answer (score 0):

The term *partially applied map* implies that the *map* function is partially applied. This is confusing.

The general principal you are looking for is **curry**. The function `map` in your example normally takes two parameters in Python. If you **curry** `map(fn, list)` to produce `map'(fn)` and then **apply** `map'(fn)` to `len`, you get a new function `map_len()`, and then you can apply `map_len` to a list of the appropriate type.

You can search for terms in functional programming, such as `curry`, `compose` and `apply`.

Comment: _partially applied map implies that the map function is partially applied._

I'm not sure why this confusing. You seem to have understood precisely what I meant.

And no, I am not looking for currying I am looking for partially applied function. I understand both can be identical and even cause confusion at times but I assure you I do mean partially applied function and not curryied function.